# python dash failed to fetch, failed to read from JSON

Tags: python, json, fetch, plotly-dash

Recently i have been working with dash, and randomly but rarely these two errors show up. I have no idea why. My program is huge and i do not know what is the problematic part of it. I cannot really replicate the errors. Do you have any suggestions what to look for?

At the failed to fetch problem this is a more detailed error:
dash.exceptions.DependencyException: "dash_renderer" is registered but the path requested is not valid.

Comment: If you haven't found error making line then at least provide complete error message!

Comment: catch the error and print everything.